# Sync Sqlite db with Oracle 10g

Tags: android, sqlite, oracle10g

My android application is connected with Sqlite3 db. I want to sync this data with oracle db on a regular basis (may be via a batch program or something API calls which i need to decide).

Edit: **Reason for data sync concept rather than using a web service directly is** the user will enter/update the data using the android app from some place where he wont get the network connectivity.

Is it possible to sync **Sqlite3 db** with a **Oracle 10g db** via **oracle mobile server**? The version compatibility is one of the major concern for me, hence want to confirm before giving it a go.

Again, is there some other way or some better way to achieve the same?

I don't have any idea about the same. Please suggest the best way to proceed.

Regards,